# Sorting a list with entries in string format

Tags: python, sorting

In Python, have a list with items (strings) that look like this:

```
"1.120e+03 8.140e+02 3.234e+01 1.450e+00 1.623e+01 7.940e+02 3.113e+01 1.580e+00 1.463e+01"
```

I want to sort this list based on the size of the first number in each string (smallest to largest). In the above case that would be `"1.120e+03"`.

I can think of a couple of ways to do it, but they involve creating new lists and a couple of for loops which I guess isn't so efficient (or elegant). Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sorting it more than once, I suggest you create your Class for the data and override methods for comparing such as `__lt__`.